# Is there a way to restrict blender renders to a predetermined 256-color palette?

Tags: rendering

I suspect there isn't, as this sort of thing is rather retro these days. But any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to say "no".  Fortunately there are tools like ImageMagick that [make it fairly easy to quantize images as a separate step](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/).